# How can I get an old, low resolution monitor set to the appropriate resolution when it is connected via a HDMI adapter?

Tags: display

I have an old wee 600x480 CRT monitor hooked up to a Pi 2 using a HDMI to VGA adapter. When I boot the Pi with this adapter attached, the resolution is set incorrectly for the monitor and I am not able to change the resolution to the required 600x480. Specifically, if I run the command `xrandr -s 640x480`, I am presented with the message `Size 640x480 not found in available modes`.

However, if I unplug the HDMI connector from the Pi and plug in a more modern monitor, I *then* can change the resolution to 640x480 using the above command and I then can re-attach the original HDMI to VGA adapter and the CRT then works.

How should I proceed to ensure that I can set the appropriate resolution without having to plug in another monitor?

Comment: perhaps some [HDMI configuration](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/config_txt.html#hdmi-mode) in `config.txt`

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately the settings I've tried in config.txt have not worked. What I really need to do is to boot the Pi with the old monitor attached to it and to then have access to the GUI running on the Pi via SSH, so I can troubleshoot (while being actually able to see the commands, as the monitor is currently not set up correctly). Would you have any idea of how I might do this?